# editing style for custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editing

how do i set editing style for custom UItableviewcell like this image.[image]

this is shopping cart view ,so i am gonna have many UITableViewCell, out of other fields only Qty field is going to be editable.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell above looks like a custom button. What you can do is to add two UIButtons to a subclass of UITableViewCell, as well as a UITextField, and add event handling code for clicking the UIButtons to update the quantity. Since you can use an image for UIButtons achieving the above look shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: problem i am getting right now is, this buttons should be visible only in editing mode? how do i get custom cell in editing mode?

Comment: When the table is set into Editing mode, all UITableViewCells will have [setEditing:animated:] called. Use that method to show/hide the appropriate UI controls.

Comment: thanks futureelite7, here is what i am doing.in [setEditing] method, i am again calling [tableview reloaddata] and in [cellforrowatindexpath] method i am check (self.editing). if its editing then load editable cell from NIB. is this correct way, and another thing how do i catch events from cell and identify which button clicked and which textfield to get update.

Answer (score 0):

i have figure out some way, i dont know its the right way,but it works for me, but still waiting the most correct way. here is what i did,

1) i have created a IBOutlat for my UIButton in my EditCellView (subclass of UITableviewcell)
2) and then i create IBAction in my tableviewcontroller
3) then i set UIButton Touch in event to IBAction in tableviewcontroller
4) in IBaction method you can get that cell using this code

```
EditItemController *cell =  (EditItemController *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.maintable indexPathForCell:cell];
```

this line of code may depends on your view layout

```
[[sender superview] superview]
```

to get correct superview you can use following command in gdb

```
gdb>po [[sender superview] superview]
```